# Using Riverpod 2.0 provider to create providers

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am trying to manage state by using the riverpod 2.0 flutter package.

Here is my .yaml entry to show that I have the latest version:

```
flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.0
```

Here is what I am trying to do. When I log into the app I want to store a few variables so they can be used later in other areas of the app.

I was learning how to do this but it was brought to my attention that I was using old features. I want to learn the correct way to do this so I am changing to different ways of creating, reading, and updating providers. I need your help in doing this since the documentation doesn't seem to be updated yet.

Here is the code for the GlobalsProviders. These providers replace the global variables I was using.

```
class GlobalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  GlobalsProvider._();

  //  *****  PROVIDERS  *****

  // This is assigned in the Login screen
  static final currentUid = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final currentUEmail = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');

  // This is assigned in  agent_profile screen
  static final agentDocumentId = Provider<String>((ref) => '');

  // ======  populated in login_screen.dart  =======
  static final companyIdProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => '');
  static final mlsIdProvider = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final currentTrxnIdProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => '');
  static final currentCompanyNameProvider = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final currentCompanyStateProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => '');
  static final currentUserIdProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => '');
  static final currentUserStateProvider = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final currentUserNameProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => '');
  // ===============================================
  static final selectedStateProvider = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final selectedUserStateProvider = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final selectedTrxnStateProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => '');
  static final selectedCompanyProvider = Provider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final selectedUserProvider = Provider<String>((ref) => '');
  static final targetScreenProvider = Provider<int>((ref) => 0);
  static final newEventProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) => true);

  static final newTrxnProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) => true);
  static final newUserProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) => true);
  static final newCompanyProvider = Provider<bool>((ref) => true);
}
```

Here is the login screen code. Here I am still using the incorrect method of populating or updating the providers:

```
class LoginScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'login_screen'; 

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends ConsumerState<LoginScreen> {
  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late String email;
  late String password;

  getCurrentAgencyName() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgentProfile =
        await agentsRef.doc(ref.watch(GlobalsProvider.currentUid)).get();

    if (_currentAgentProfile != null) {
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.companyId.notifier).state = _currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserStateProvider.notifier).state = _currentAgentProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.mlsId.notifier).state = _currentAgentProfile.get('mlsId');
    }

    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgencyProfile =
        await agencyRef.doc(ref.watch(GlobalsProvider.companyId)).get(); 

    if (_currentAgencyProfile != null) {
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyState.notifier).state = _currentAgencyProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyName.notifier).state = _currentAgencyProfile.get('name');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool loginFail = false;
    String errorMessage = "";

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // children: [
          //   Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',
          //       fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
          // ],
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // This fixes the keyboard white space
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 48.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect email' : null,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect passwowrd' : null,
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen())),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Forgot Password',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    showSpinner = true;
                  });
                  try {
                    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth
                        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password);

                    if (userCredential != null) {
                      // Set the global state
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state = _auth.currentUser!.email;
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state = 0;
                      await getCurrentAgencyName();
                      Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                      );
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        loginFail = true;
                      });
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = false;
                    });
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                    switch (error.code) {
                      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                      case "invalid-email":
                        errorMessage =
                        "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                        break;
                      case "email-already-in-use":
                        errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                      case "wrong-password":
                        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                      case "user-not-found":
                        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                      case "user-disabled":
                        errorMessage =
                        "User with this email has been disabled.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                      case "too-many-requests":
                        errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                      case "operation-not-allowed":
                        errorMessage =
                        "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                        break;
                      default:
                        errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                    }

                    if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                    }
                  }
                }
              ),
              RoundedButton(
                title: 'Log In',
                colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    showSpinner = true;
                  });
                  try {
                    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth
                        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password);

                    if (userCredential != null) {
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state = _auth.currentUser!.email;
                      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state = 0;
                      await getCurrentAgencyName();
                      Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                      );
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        loginFail = true;
                      });
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = false;
                    });
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                    switch (error.code) {
                      case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                      case "invalid-email":
                        errorMessage =
                        "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                        break;
                      case "email-already-in-use":
                        errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                      case "wrong-password":
                        errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                      case "user-not-found":
                        errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                      case "user-disabled":
                        errorMessage =
                        "User with this email has been disabled.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                      case "too-many-requests":
                        errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                        break;
                      case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                      case "operation-not-allowed":
                        errorMessage =
                        "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                        break;
                      default:
                        errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                    }

                    if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                    }
                  }
                }),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'New User?  Create Account',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => UserRegisterScreen())),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My questions are,
Am I creating the providers in the proper way?

Once the providers are created, how do I update the state and how do I get the value from the provider?

This is all new to me so I hope you excuse my ignorance.
Thanks

Comment: Provider doesn't have a public notifier.  It's designed to be updated only by the ref.watch and ref.listen it has set up in the create callback.  Perhaps you want a Notifier/NotifierProvider pair instead?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what I want. I am learning flutter through making an app. I was maintaining state by using global variables but I knew that was the wrong way to do it. Now, I am trying to do it by using the riverpod 2.0 package.  I will update the original post to explain what I am trying to do.